# python : decode strings

Tags: python, base64, decode

Can someone give an advice of how to decode these strings? 
They are parts of email subjects.

`=?Windows-1251?B?ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI?=`

`=?koi8-r?B?5tLPzM/XwSDtwdLJzsEg98nUwczYxdfOwQ?=`

`=?Windows-1251?B?1PDu6+7i4CDM4PDo7eAgwujy4Ov85eLt4A?=`

It's probably necessary to take inner part of string `ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI` and then `base64.decodestring(string).decode('windows-1251')`
Such an approach works in most cases, but not with these strings :(

```
base64.decodestring('ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/alecs/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.6/base64.pyc in decodestring(s)
    319 def decodestring(s):
    320     """Decode a string."""
--> 321     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
    322 
    323 

Error: Incorrect padding
```

Comment: Write your code in a readable manner, and include any output or errors you've got.

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? What information are you trying to extract from them?

Comment: `'=?ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI?='.decode('base-64').decode('windows-1251')` does work ...

Comment: These *look* like e-mail headers, encoded, but with such scarce data, I can't be sure. Would you mind sharing some more context with us?

Comment: `'=?koi8-r?B?5tLPzM/XwSDtwdLJzsEg98nUwczYxdfOwQ?='.decode('base-64').decode('windows-1251')` works as well :::

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: You're decoding the "=?" and "?=" delimiters, too -- but those shouldn't be part of the base64 string? @eat: you're even including the encoding information ("koi8-r","B"), surely that's not part of the string -- also, the "koi8-r" is the encoding specified and should replace "windows-1251" in your call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test = [
    '=?Windows-1251?B?ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI?=',
    '=?koi8-r?B?5tLPzM/XwSDtwdLJzsEg98nUwczYxdfOwQ?=',
    '=?Windows-1251?B?1PDu6+7i4CDM4PDo7eAgwujy4Ov85eLt4A?='
]

def decodeStr(s):
    s = s.split('?')
    enc = s[1]
    dat = s[3]

    return (dat+'===').decode('base-64').decode(enc)

for t in test:
    print decodeStr(t)
```

Comment: You are right, but don't understand why it's neccessary to add == to the end :( maybe something wrong with this strings ...

Comment: base64 works by regrouping bits; it turns 3 8-bit chars into 4 6-bit chars (then refills the empty top bits with 0s). To reverse this, it expects 4 chars at a time - the length of your string must be a multiple of 4 characters. The '=' chars are recognized as padding; three chars of padding is enough to make any string a multiple of 4 chars long.

Answer (score 2):

It seems those strings were incorrectly encoded, without padding in the end. A base64 string should always have a multiple of 4 characters. The padding character is =, you can add it by hand if the length is not a multiple of 4. Here are the results for your examples:

```
>>> print "ICLRLcvu5Obo8fLo6iI=".decode ('base-64').decode ('Windows-1251')
 "С-Лоджистик"
>>> print "5tLPzM/XwSDtwdLJzsEg98nUwczYxdfOwQ==".decode ('base-64').decode ('koi8-r')
Фролова Марина Витальевна
>>> print "1PDu6+7i4CDM4PDo7eAgwujy4Ov85eLt4A==".decode ('base-64').decode ('Windows-1251')
Фролова Марина Витальевна
```

Note the addition of 1, 2 and 2 '=' signs, respectively.